# What do I need to check why log_reuse_wait_desc keeps coming back to REPLICATION

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

What should I do to check or need to do why log_reuse_wait_desc is **REPLICATION**?

A database of ours keeps coming back to **REPLICATION** for the log_reuse_wait_desc   after essentially following this https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2871474/sql-transaction-log-grows-when-you-use-change-data-capture-for-oracle

*Note: This is not CDC for Oracle but instead the DB, before I came in as DBA, was using CDC and eventually disabled when it was restored to Standard Edition ( CDC is EE only )*

In our case, since CDC is not available in Standard Edition and there's no way to proceed as directed by the link, I enabled Snapshot replication for a test storedprocedure so that I can  perform the "fix."  When log_reuse_desc_wait becomes **NOTHING**, I perform log backup and shrink the log I then remove the replication.

Now in a matter of minutes, log_reuse_desc_wait returns to REPLICATION and since the log has been reduced, I wait for this again to grow and do the dance again.

***Server info***

> Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> Sql Server 2014 Standard Edition
>      (SP3)

**Update**: I can consistently replicate that log_reuse_wait becomes **REPLICATION** from **NOTHING** once the log backup starts. I am not really sure why.

Comment: Since you dont need replication - can you just run `sp_removedbreplication 'database_name'` ? Let me know if that helps or not.

Comment: Hi @Kin, no it did not. thanks